# Does command line supports the printscreen key of keyboard? if so what is the command to do it?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

Is there a way to execute printscreen key of the keyboard from the command prompt?

```
 mkdir folder '  creates folder
 start some.exe ' runs the exe file
```

Now how do I capture the window as a screen shot from command prompt instead of pressing print screen key?

Actually does command line support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to batch-run a print screen, but you can pipe screen output to a file using syntax similar to

```
dir *.* > dirlist.txt
print dirlist.txt
```

(or use >> to append to an existing file). This redirection works in DOS/Windows-cmd/Unix